# Cant find SignalR Hub Class in Add New Item dialog vs 2017

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, signalr-hub

I am trying to create chat function using .net core and signalR. I added Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR nuget package to my project, but vs not showing SignalR hub class item in add new item list. Then how can I add hubclass ??

Answer (score 2):

A `hub` class is created by inheriting `Hub` like below rather than in the Add New Item list of vs.Refer to [Create a SignalR hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#create-a-signalr-hub)

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SignalRChat.Hubs
    {
        public class ChatHub : Hub
        {
            public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
            {
                await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @B.Nishan Great.Could you accept the answer if your problem has been resolved?